# Navigation Not working in winJS

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

### Navigation Not working in winJS

I am trying to call a navigation on a button click.But its not working
    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("Views/Login/Login.html",null);

Comment: Define not working. Do you get an error? Did you hook up anything to the navigation events? What project template (if any) did you start from?

Comment: You have a relative URL path there, so it's looking beneath the current location for a subdirectory called Views.  Try an absolute path to the root of the app by adding the forward slash before Views - WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/Views/Login/Login.html",null);

Comment: thanks..i fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the proper winjs navigation page control to setup your page control container to accept single page navigation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx